# Run-Time Error 1004 VBA - VLookup on second instance of for loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, vlookup

I am having an issue with VLookup in my VBA code. When I didn't have the range as a dynamic size using CurrentRegion it worked flawlessly, now for whatever reason, it only works for a single loop over and fails at the first VLookup. I have tried with and without the with block. I have a variable that will replace the 5 in the for loop and works but have kept it as its original so that isn't affecting it.

I apologize if this is a duplicate but I could not find an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Set jobTypeData = Worksheets("JobType").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To 5
    jobTypeTemp = Worksheets("Employees2").Cells(i + 1, 16).Value
    jobRoleTemp = Worksheets("Employees2").Cells(i + 1, 17).Value
    
    'Creates variables relevant to the job type
    With Worksheets("JobType")
        minHours = CDec(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobTypeTemp, jobTypeData, 2))
        maxHours = CDec(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobTypeTemp, jobTypeData, 3))
        minShift = CDec(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobTypeTemp, jobTypeData, 5))
        maxShift = CDec(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobTypeTemp, jobTypeData, 6))
        shiftGap = CDec(WorksheetFunction.VLookup(jobTypeTemp, jobTypeData, 7))
    End With
```

There is more code under this but it all works a-okay and worked fine before using the dynamic data size.
The code that works does not change the contents or size of jobTypeData.
I have also checked the values VLookup returns and they are all correct. The only thing I can think of is that it can't find the second jobType however I have checked and they are identical (no hidden spaces).

Comment: Fails how? What's the error? It worked OK for me. I suspect `CurrentRegion` isn't returning what you want. Put a breakpoint on the `For` line and enter `?jobTypeData.Address` in the immediate window and see what you get.

Comment: I just tried that and it is returning exactly what is expected, first and second loop over.
The error is 1004 run-time error  "Application-defined or object-defined error".
The error occurs at the VLookup, I put a breakpoint at the first and second VLookup, first pass over is no issues, second pass over, I get the above error after attempting to run the first VLookup

Comment: Are there more codes after the vlookup?

Comment: There is a LOT of code after it (118 more lines in the loop), but what I don't understand is that not only did it work prior to using CurrentRegion, but CurrentRegion doesn't change (as evidenced by my previous comment checking .Address), none of the values used in the code shown are changed at all throughout the rest of it and only used for mathematical equations to alter stuff on a completely separate non-interacting worksheet. And because it works the first time around as well I am honestly very confused.

Comment: When you say second pass, you mean when `i = 2`? What's the value of jobTypeTemp when you get the error?

Comment: Yes, i = 2. JobTypeTemp is "Full-Time", the first pass over was "Part-Time". I checked for hidden spaces in the comparison and there aren't any, I haven't changed any of those values since switching to the dynamic range.

Comment: I think switching to the dynamic range is just a coincidence. Unless you tell me you can change it back to a static range and it works. I think something else changed and you don't realize it. Can you put a VLOOKUP formula in a spare cell on the worksheet and see that it works?

Comment: OKAY, well I found out what the issue was and I am still thoroughly confused. I thought it wouldnt matter if vlookup was exact or not because it was always except due to data validation however, it somehow thought "Role Name" was a closer match to "Team Manager" than "Team Manager" was and thought "Type Name" was closer to "Full-Time" than "Full-Time" was. Although it taught me to use exact match, that is clearly a bug in VLookup's approximate match. Don't know why it was working before though...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be related to the way VLookup uses 'approximate match'.

I always thought VLookup would still provide the exact match if it was an option and because I had strict data validation I never thought using approximate match would be a problem. However, turns out, it's not just mildly unpredictable, but actually unreliable.

After checking it was assuming "Role Name" was a closer match to "Team Manager" than "Team Manager". Upon changing it to using 'exact match', everything worked fine. No changes to the code which worked before either.
Well, lesson learned...

When you have an exact match ALWAYS use (no matter how confident you are, use me as an example):

```
VLOOKUP(arg1, arg2, arg3, FALSE)
```

Not:

```
VLOOKUP(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: Good catch. The approximate match option uses a binary search algorithm. I think it's totally predictable if you know the algorithm but that's not much help.  If it chooses the "wrong" tree on it's first evaluation, it will never find "Team Manager" because it lives on the other half of the binary tree. My rule is always use FALSE unless I have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the input and I appreciate the help.